# Do numpy.savez and numpy.savez_compressed use pickle?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I recently encountered numpy.savez and numpy.savez_compressed.  Both seem to work well with arrays of differing types, including object arrays.  However, numpy.load does not work well with object type arrays.  For example:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.full((10, 1), np.pi)
strings = np.full((10, 1), "letters", dtype=object)

np.savez("test.npz", numbers=numbers, strings=strings)

data = np.load("test.npz")
```

Calling `data["strings"]` throws the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

However, enabling pickle on `numpy.load` resolves this issue.  Pickling is not discussed within the `numpy.savez` and `numpy.savez_compressed` documents...which makes me wonder why pickle is required to load the data.  Do `numpy.savez` and `numpy.savez_compressed` use pickle automatically behind the scenes?

Comment: It's because you have `dtype=object`. Since `object` is not a c-type, `numpy` doesn't know how to save it so it is trying to default to `pickle` to save it. Change `dtype=str` and see if that works.

Comment: @Jason Oh no, changing dtype to str definitely works.  I set the dtype to object on purpose because that seems to force it to be pickled.  I'm just trying to confirm that savez and savez_compressed actually use pickle in the background since this is not mentioned within the documentation.

Comment: @ntkepp got it. Yea `object` is a Python type so `numpy` doesn't know what to do with it and `pickle` is often the default when serializing Python types.

Comment: `savez` saves each array as a `npy` file in a `zip` archive.  In other words, it uses `save` for each argument.  If that argument is not a numpy array, it will be 'wrapped' in an `object` dtype array.  All non-array objects are saved with the `pickle` format.

Comment: @Jason Ah, that makes sense.  Maybe I should have known that.

Comment: For `save`, the default value for `allow_pickle` is True, while for `load`, it is `False`.  That `load` value applies whether it's loading a `npy` or a `npz`.

Comment: @hpaulj Understood, but there is no mention of this in the savez/savez_compression documents...hence my misunderstanding.  Thanks for the comments, by the way.

Comment: I suppose the devs were so used to thinking of `savez` as an extension of `save` that they didn't think the pickle option needed to be included or documented. The [source] code links might yield more insights to what they were thinking (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `dtype=object` for that, pickle will be used (serializing Python objects).

Serializing with pickle is allowed by default when saving, but deserializing pickles must be explicitly requested when loading. That's because loading pickled data can execute arbitrary code, and for untrusted input this would be a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

> Do np.savez and np.savez_compressed use pickle automatically behind the scenes?

For object-type data, yes.

For other kinds of data, such as floats, ints, longs, or bytes, pickle is not used.

There is no equivalent of `allow_pickle` for np.save(), because loading pickled objects can be a security issue, but saving pickled objects is not.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes the pickle module is used.

Look for "Loading files that contain object arrays uses the `pickle`                module" in below source link.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L555-L639

Comment: I understand this in regards to loading the data, but it may be nice to have the default behavior (i.e., pickleing objects) mentioned within the documents for np.savez.  That said, I'm trying to understand if this is something I should have just assumed.

Comment: Ok Got it. Ya the document should have mentioned in it.